# Adding points with defined intervals in QGIS

Tags: qgis, map-drawing

I'm trying to make a grid with points of defined intervals (e.g. 5 m). How can I achieve this with QGIS?

Answer (score 5):

You want the regular grid tool

[image]

[image]